# Concrete steps along exterior wall

Tags: concrete, waterproofing, stairs

I'm building concrete steps along the hillside parallel to my exterior wall.
Lower part of the wall is concrete foundation and upper part is stucco/felt paper/plywood and wall studs. Part of the steps will be against the stucco.

I know I need a water barrier between the concrete and the stucco part of the wall. 
Can I just use felt paper? Or self-adhered flashing?
I was thinking originally of using galvanized steel roll along the wall but it would be a pain to cut it to match the steps along the wall.

Note : I've used rubber paint to reseal my foundation and I'll have a french drain under the concrete steps.

Also, this is in Socal (not much rain), and this wall is covered by a large eave (so water is not coming down that wall).

Thanks.

[image: hillside concrete stairway]

Answer (score 1):

Of the 3 options you mentioned,  self-adhered flashing is the best option for a barrier.  However, I would take care to have a metal dripper above the flashing to ensure rainwater along the wall does not seep down between the flashing and the stucco.